MySQL memory_global_total vs memory of mysqld
I currently trying to find out why my DB sometimes runs out of memory.
Its running inside a docker container with resource limits set (4GB).
Using performance schema tables/views I do not see why it runs out of memory.
e.g. select * from x$memory_global_total; gives me 3.5 GiB of usage. Using ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size I get 4 GiB so there will be a OOM kill soonish. But I wonder where this difference is coming from.
Looking through the other perfomance schema tables I didn't see why this difference is there.
Using SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + @@innodb_log_buffer_size + @@max_connections * (@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size + @@join_buffer_size + @@tmp_table_size )) / (1024*1024*1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB; I get to 3.3530 so the 4GB should be fine from my understanding.

It could be a memory leak bug in MySQL Server. There have been several such bugs reported in MySQL 8.0 versions. Performance schema only measures the memory usage that is instrumented.

Cf: https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=memory+leak&bug_type%5B%5D=Server&status%5B%5D=All&severity=&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=8.0&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&cpu_arch=0&cpu_arch_details=&last_updated=0&tags=&similar=

Interesting. Have to maybe check there a bit more. On the other hand most of the reported issues are closed, rejected or never got any feedback.

You didn't say what version of MySQL you are using, so you could be using a version that had a memory leak bug, which has been fixed in a later version, and therefore the bug was closed. Or you could be experiencing a memory leak bug that has not been reported yet.

Also Oracle takes bugs off of the public bug site if they contain any information that could be exploited for a security related issue. So there could be other bugs, fixed or not, which are not public.
